# Getting rails-api and strong_parameters to work together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, strong-parameters

When including

```
gem 'strong_parameters'
gem 'rails-api'
```

together in my `Gemfile`, calling `params.require` like

```
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
  end
```

fails with the following error on the `require()` call.

```
TypeError:
   can't convert Symbol into String
```

The backtrace shows `strong_parameters`'  `ActionController::StrongParameters`' `require()` method is never hit.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I spent too long on this one, so I figured I'd share here to hopefully save someone else a bit of time.

The error above comes from the [`require()`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb#L225) method in `ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable` being executed when calling

```
params.require(:user)...
```

`strong_parameters` injects `ActionController::StrongParameters` into `ActionController::Base` at the bottom of [this file](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/blob/master/lib/action_controller/parameters.rb#L148) with

```
ActionController::Base.send :include, ActionController::StrongParameters
```

The `rails-api` gem requires your app's `ApplicationController` extend `ActionController::API` in favor of `ActionController::Base`

The application controllers don't know anything about `ActionController::StrongParameters` because they're not extending the class `ActionController::StrongParameters` was included within. This is why the `require()` method call is not calling the implementation in `ActionController::StrongParameters`.

To tell `ActionController::API` about `ActionController::StrongParameters` is as simple as adding the following to a file in `config/initializers`.

```
ActionController::API.send :include, ActionController::StrongParameters
```

Comment: I actually tries to require a file as code and expects the filename to be a String, hence the error.

Answer (score 5):

This problem can be solved by including the **rails_api master git branch** in your Gemfile as below:

```
gem 'rails-api', git: 'https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api.git', branch: 'master'
```

rails_api gem has fixed this [issue](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/commit/04846e05b7b57d7811bb8df1d6b44b0c12318877) by including the below lines at [api.rb](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/blob/master/lib/rails-api/action_controller/api.rb)

```
if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR == 4
   include StrongParameters
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a [pull request](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/pull/144) (currently open) that should fix this behavior. Instead of calling `ActionController::API.send`, this should be included with...

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  include ActionController::StrongParameters
end
```